# Please tell me what am i doing wrong in the following java code

Tags: java, visual-c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I am reading a binary file in which numerical data is stored in 16 bit form.  when this file is read visual c++ program, it is working fine, but when i am using the following java code i can't get the desired results and the output seems to be garbage values. I am using `RandomAccessFile` as u can see. But i am getting absolutely absurd values. One thing more, i have floating point values stored in this file, but even when i am using `readFloat()`, or `readInt()` or `readShort()`, i am unable to get desired result. Please point me where am i going wrong.                                                      **first 10 bytes in the  file** : 01100000 00000000 00100011 00100000 11000000 00100011 11000001 00100010 10111111 00100001 .*everybody thanks for giving ur time*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile data = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\RawEEGData.bin","r");
        try {
            while(data != null) {

                // i have tried readFloat(), readShort() and readInt()
                // but none of them seems to be working
                float myInt16 = data.readFloat(); 

                System.out.printf(" %f\n", myInt16);
            }
        } finally {
            if (data != null) { data.close(); };
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure your data are stored in BigInt IEEE754 and start at the beginning of the file ? What are the errors ?

Comment: You need to be more clear about what this "16 bit form numerical data" is.

Comment: And are you sure Java and C++ use the same endianness in the current context?

Comment: actually the guy who wrote the corresponding c++ code told me that it is numerical data in 16 bit form, i.e 16 bits of the data file correspond to one data point. He used ReadInt16() to extract the data in his code and it was working fine. So i guess it must be int type.

Comment: please don't close this post. i need solution to this problem desperately.

Comment: @PéterTörök i get ur point, but i tried using reverseBytes() to change the endiannes to Big endian, but still i m not getting the correct output.

Comment: @dystroy the data is composed entirely with 16 bit ints from beginning to end. i saw the file using binary viewer software and theguy who used the file earlier told me that two consequtive 8 bit chunks(i.e 2 consequtive bytes) form a single data point. so i guess it is normal 16 bit int of c++ (or short in java)                                                                 the error is that i m getting absurd output i.e values should come within the range (-10 to 10) but it is coming out in millions as well.

Comment: You need to compare the results byte to byte with the file input. I.e. read first a sequence of byte values and print them, then compare these with the bytes in the file. If they match, repeat with reading short values and printing their extracted bytes each - this may give you a clue.

Comment: Ok, so that's not float. This is maybe just a matter of endianness. Try to build your first int (a java `short`, in fact) in reverse order : `(b1<<8)+b0`

Comment: "He used ReadInt16() to extract the data in his code and it was working fine." and "i have floating point values stored in this file" does not compute for me.

Comment: I suppose that's not at all floating point values. There is no 2 bytes IEEE754 format, so if it's float it's a specific building.

Comment: @esej i m a little confused in that myself, because these values are taken from an eeg experiment where data can be float or integer, but still he had used ReadInt16() to read the entire file.

Comment: There is no recent standard 16 bits floating point format. There may be a convention in your code to use a fixed point. Or maybe those floats are on 4 bytes.

Comment: 1) I think that you should give us a couple of bytes of the file, at least 8. 2) The info you're getting from the "other guy" obv. isn't enough - maybe you can try to find out more exactly how the file is/was created.

Comment: ok so here are the first 10 bytes on the file :     01100000 00000000 00100011 00100000 11000000 00100011 11000001 00100010 10111111 00100001 .everybody thanks for giving ur time

Comment: Is the first number 512, and the others near zero both negative and positive numbers? (512,0,-2,-2,-1 or similar?)

Comment: (or:skipping first value:0.008079529,0.015136719,0.013191223,0.011222839)

Comment: hey guys, i got to know from my colleague that the fist number is to keep a count, the rest of the series is something like this : first no., 8227, 9152, 8897, 8639, 8404, 4135,.....which can be obtained by reversing the bytes that i had provided earlier. So it it had to be an endianness problem, but friends, even after reversing the order of bytes, taking care of the endianness, my output is not matching with the given series. what should i do now. i m doomed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an endianness problem. And if your colleage used ReadInt16, those numbers aren't floats. Try this :

```
  byte b0 = data.readByte();
  byte b1 = data.readByte();
  int i = (((int)b1)<<8) + b0;
  System.out.print(" int value : " + i);
```

EDIT : if that doesn't work, edit your question to display the 8 first bytes as `10101000 01...` or hexa

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what the *int16* data really is:

- byte order (endianess) ?
- signed or unsigned?
- twos complement or something else?

Unless you *know* what form the data has you won't be able to interpret it correctly. Depending on what it turns out to be, the provided methods on RandomAccessFile may be useless, since they only cover the formats commonly used in java.

Most likely the problem is that VC++ stores the data in platform dependend order while Java always uses big endian byte order (aka network byte order).